# Device not listed under Develop Tap in Safari( for Debug)

Tags: safari, mobile-device-management

I have upgraded the os X 10.8.5

[image]

and safari

[image]

the device not listed under safari develop menu, i need this for debugging.

tried **restart the safari and reconnected the device more times but it is not working**.

the same device working in another MacBookPro with safari version 6.0.

Could you please help me?.